# Apple PassKit, webservice invoked hundres of times

Tags: java, ios, spring, passkit

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2, Spring Data REST, hibernate in my REST application. I'm trying to manage Apple loyalty cards.
I'm using [jpasskit](https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit) to generate the pass (.pkpass bundle) and it works like a charm. Because I want to manage updates of the pass, I set the webServiceUrl.

I implemented all endpoints described in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html) but I'm facing two big issues:

1. as soon I install the pass in my phone, Apple start to send me a LOT of register requests (just for one phone). Every request has a different `deviceLibraryIdentifier` (I know it's normal, it's not guaranteed that the phone sends the same identifier every time). With "a lot" I mean hundreds in few minutes. I reply with HTTP 201 because every request has a different `deviceLibraryIdentifier`
2. When Apple call the endpoint GET request to `webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag` the `passesUpdatedSince` is always empty, even if I set it when I reply. I also checked the Apple server example and what I do it seems correct to me

These are my apache logs where you can see POST requests from Apple and the result code HTTP 
201. This is just a small extract from logs:

```
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:27 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/7606fc820e255dd6cbafb2cf56ca80a583d195d1a6793facb56261493215d187/v1/devices/f7cace9f54587f6bd97bd3d1a56257f6/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4503 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:28 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/7606fc820e255dd6cbafb2cf56ca80a583d195d1a6793facb56261493215d187/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962470 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:29 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c7d0e84d62aeb08fae867a0282756c7a7cb51460b7aa77868e5072b670b33ce8/v1/devices/1d50e6abd5d39c2e828630cb62a7a031/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:29 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c7d0e84d62aeb08fae867a0282756c7a7cb51460b7aa77868e5072b670b33ce8/v1/devices/1d50e6abd5d39c2e828630cb62a7a031/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4503 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:30 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c7d0e84d62aeb08fae867a0282756c7a7cb51460b7aa77868e5072b670b33ce8/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962469 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:31 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/6a96c74bb40236a16e7c881762b24359274f89a5bdd20d9418c7154d6466450d/v1/devices/5967d02cf3563d106c784498af11279f/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:31 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/6a96c74bb40236a16e7c881762b24359274f89a5bdd20d9418c7154d6466450d/v1/devices/5967d02cf3563d106c784498af11279f/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:32 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/6a96c74bb40236a16e7c881762b24359274f89a5bdd20d9418c7154d6466450d/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962470 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:33 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/8f17da01585e31f725de56205c55a74ff2e18d4c1fffffee7d9912ed7266ffe8/v1/devices/c9316a73d0343819de852ec508459bb1/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:34 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/8f17da01585e31f725de56205c55a74ff2e18d4c1fffffee7d9912ed7266ffe8/v1/devices/c9316a73d0343819de852ec508459bb1/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:34 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/8f17da01585e31f725de56205c55a74ff2e18d4c1fffffee7d9912ed7266ffe8/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962470 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:36 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/64f4fcfbc3c5f897dc18858de503fd413a73d5856cc811e51b479764ec0d37cc/v1/devices/2de84de20f3afdffd8ef101305f9e45e/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:36 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/64f4fcfbc3c5f897dc18858de503fd413a73d5856cc811e51b479764ec0d37cc/v1/devices/2de84de20f3afdffd8ef101305f9e45e/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:36 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/64f4fcfbc3c5f897dc18858de503fd413a73d5856cc811e51b479764ec0d37cc/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962468 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:38 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/1ef24ad8294860ad7e1e9fe6a097ff32146c1278cf43c391ba34d29d4461cad7/v1/devices/0b1814d6e7bad039f2f87d0ea6f2a329/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:38 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/1ef24ad8294860ad7e1e9fe6a097ff32146c1278cf43c391ba34d29d4461cad7/v1/devices/0b1814d6e7bad039f2f87d0ea6f2a329/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4503 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:38 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/1ef24ad8294860ad7e1e9fe6a097ff32146c1278cf43c391ba34d29d4461cad7/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962466 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:40 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/eca5ec7bb9ffd94ea54fbc7a49eba154575a803c4f30fc38068fc8d4e7ff5805/v1/devices/a78ad2681e9db6345e147aa98e584fdb/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:40 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/eca5ec7bb9ffd94ea54fbc7a49eba154575a803c4f30fc38068fc8d4e7ff5805/v1/devices/a78ad2681e9db6345e147aa98e584fdb/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:40 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/eca5ec7bb9ffd94ea54fbc7a49eba154575a803c4f30fc38068fc8d4e7ff5805/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962470 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:42 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/981006aec2e42801b6225709730e9a62bf153d86ce1c744336aec2055c181187/v1/devices/be13bd781f4a562b730e7e91297b791e/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:42 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/981006aec2e42801b6225709730e9a62bf153d86ce1c744336aec2055c181187/v1/devices/be13bd781f4a562b730e7e91297b791e/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:42 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/981006aec2e42801b6225709730e9a62bf153d86ce1c744336aec2055c181187/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962472 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:44 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/3d219f4af590fb708722603352d019fffdcc468a3b616f24f0a704ba61f5b529/v1/devices/733a9d529d4ceac53b8f18f98c7bd5df/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:44 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/3d219f4af590fb708722603352d019fffdcc468a3b616f24f0a704ba61f5b529/v1/devices/733a9d529d4ceac53b8f18f98c7bd5df/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:44 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/3d219f4af590fb708722603352d019fffdcc468a3b616f24f0a704ba61f5b529/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962467 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:46 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c8332e193912bb852abd0b3aa66aa0081e2882e7d30e3242e28818a345954846/v1/devices/f23c49f1ec6a0059434877840275d5bc/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:46 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c8332e193912bb852abd0b3aa66aa0081e2882e7d30e3242e28818a345954846/v1/devices/f23c49f1ec6a0059434877840275d5bc/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:47 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/c8332e193912bb852abd0b3aa66aa0081e2882e7d30e3242e28818a345954846/v1/passes/pass.loyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c674
92dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 200 962469 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/e20f85d8257d42155b93577de34cbc244b9ff0e18d2b853cd9526b751204ff53/v1/devices/1948a632494d98f052a9261f6e2127d0/registrations/pass.l
oyalty.cloud.test/9e2df4d5-824b-4ee0-a931-c0c67492dbb5 HTTP/1.1" 201 4204 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
api-stage.com.test:443 xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Mar/2020:15:41:49 +0100] "GET /api/v1/public/apple/wallet/e20f85d8257d42155b93577de34cbc244b9ff0e18d2b853cd9526b751204ff53/v1/devices/1948a632494d98f052a9261f6e2127d0/registrations/pass.lo
yalty.cloud.test HTTP/1.1" 200 4502 "-" "passd/1.0 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0"
```

Any idea of what I could check to fix these problems? I'm testing all with an iphone 6s with iOS 13.3.1

Comment: Get the same behavior on my end. It happens on not that much devices (ie, 1% of the device I got registrations for), but I have up to tens of thousands registrations for the "buggy" devices. This looks like a Passkit bug so I would recommend to file a Radar (already did on my side).

Comment: Thanks @LorisGuignard, actually I filed a TSI at Apple several days ago but they didn't reply me yet. Not good if this is really a bug of some device. How can we handle that on server side? The push token is the same but the deviceId is not.

Comment: @LorisGuignard Did you have any feedback from Apple? I didn't get any reply so far...

Comment: they replied yesterday, but simply asked me to provide a sysdiagnose. Since the error is not happening on my own devices (but on hundreds of customer devices using my services) I am not able to generate a sysdiagnose with the bug happening. Can you try to generate one and join it to your radar? https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/Wallet_Logging_Instructions.pdf

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour on my side. It appears that the behaviour is isolated to specific passes. Did you get a resolution from Apple?